Spring Session MongoDB - How to handle attributes - Reactive
I'm confused about how to handle attributes with MongoDB Session with Spring Session. I had this working with Redis, but because lack of support from Spring, several pooling errors, and the expense of Redis Cache, means I'm hoping to switch to MongoDB
I want to save this as an attribute to the session, but am not sure how:
@Repository
internal class MongoAuthorizationRequestRepository(
    private val mongoSerialiserConfig: MongoSerialiserConfig
) : ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoSecurityContextRepository::class.java)
    private val springAuthorizationRequestAttrName: String = "AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST"

    override fun saveAuthorizationRequest(
        authorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange
    ): Mono<Void> {
        logger.info("SAVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")

        return exchange.session
            .doOnNext { session ->
                if (authorizationRequest?.state == null) {
                    logger.info("Authorization Request State cannot be empty")
                } else {
                    session.attributes[springAuthorizationRequestAttrName] = authorizationRequest
                    logger.info("Authorization Request state: ${authorizationRequest.state}")
                    logger.info("Saved Authorization Request $authorizationRequest in WebSession: $session")
                }
            }.then()
    }

    override fun loadAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        logger.info("LOADING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
        val state = getStateParameter(exchange) ?: return Mono.empty()
        return exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                val authorizationRequest = getAuthorizationRequest(session)
                if (state == authorizationRequest?.state) {
                    logger.info("Loading authorization request")
                    Mono.just(authorizationRequest)
                } else {
                    logger.warn("State in request does not match Authorization Request state in Session: $session")
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
    }

    override fun removeAuthorizationRequest(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?> {
        logger.info("REMOVING AUTHORIZATION REQUEST")
        val state = getStateParameter(exchange) ?: return Mono.empty()
        return exchange.session
            .flatMap { session ->
                val authorizationRequest = getAuthorizationRequest(session)
                if (state == authorizationRequest?.state) {
                    session.attributes.remove(this.springAuthorizationRequestAttrName)
                    logger.info("Removed authorization request")
                    Mono.just(authorizationRequest)
                } else {
                    logger.info("State in request does not match Authorization Request state in Session: $session")
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
    }

    // Helper methods
    private fun getStateParameter(exchange: ServerWebExchange): String? {
        requireNotNull(exchange) { "exchange cannot be null" }
        return exchange.request.queryParams[OAuth2ParameterNames.STATE]?.firstOrNull()
    }

    private fun getAuthorizationRequest(session: WebSession): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
        Assert.notNull(session, "session cannot be null")
        val authRequestAttr = session.getAttribute<Map<String, Any>>(springAuthorizationRequestAttrName)
        if (authRequestAttr != null) {
            // Deserialize from Map to SecurityContext
            val map = authRequestAttr as? Map<String, Any>
            try {
                val authorizationRequest = mongoSerialiserConfig.customObjectMapper()
                    .convertValue(map, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest::class.java)
                logger.info("Successfully deserialized Authorization Request: $authorizationRequest")
                return authorizationRequest
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logger.error("Error deserializing Authorization Request: ${e.message}", e)
                return null
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("No Authorization Request found in WebSession")
            return null
        }
    }

}

There are 2 converters already available:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/mongo/JacksonMongoSessionConverter.java
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/mongo/JdkMongoSessionConverter.java
 fun jdkMongoSessionConverter(): JdkMongoSessionConverter {
        val converter = JdkMongoSessionConverter(Duration.ofMinutes(7200))
        return converter
    }

    @Bean
    fun jacksonMongoSessionConverter(
        mongoSerialiserConfig: MongoSerialiserConfig
    ): JacksonMongoSessionConverter {
        return JacksonMongoSessionConverter(mongoSerialiserConfig.customObjectMapper())
    }

I've added a custom objectMapper to the 2nd one called customObjectMapper. There is too much code that this post will allow so it can be found here:
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/blob/master/Spring%20BFF/bff/auth/serialisers/MongoSerialiserConfig.kt
But the problem I have is the converters work with MongoSession and a docDB, rather than the Websession from the exchange. So how do you serialiser and de-serialise?
Any ideas?
